# What's the "send" equivalent of the scope resolution operator?

Tags: ruby

```
class Person
  DEFAULT_MALE_NAME = "Joe"
  DEFAULT_FEMALE_NAME = "Jane"

  def give_default_name
    self.name = self.class.send("DEFAULT_#{gender.upcase}_NAME")
  end

end
```

this doesn't work because "self.class.send" ends up calling User.DEFAULT_MALE_NAME where I want  it to do User::DEFAULT_MALE_NAME.

What's the equivalent of "send" for "::"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`const_get`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-const_get), but you should pass the constant name as a symbol

```
self.class.const_get(:"DEFAULT_#{gender.upcase}_NAME")
```

Comment: Ok, maybe "need to" was a bit strong. I was basing that on the documentation